# How to add weight on hook_form_alter

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I have a hook_form_alter in my module, but another module, workbench_access, also has a hook_form_alter which I need to be called before my hook_form_alter. How do I add weight to my hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the `weight` column for your module in the `system` table to higher than that of the Workbench Access module.

See [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238) for the different ways to do this. Once you have, clear Drupal's caches and your module's hooks will be called after those of Workbench Access modules (and most likely a lot of other modules).